# How to Setup cron in Windows XP with CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I am newbie. I have Windows XP and use the [CodeIgniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EllisLab#CodeIgniter) framework. I wanted to know how to set up a cron job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really make a 'real' cronjob system with PHP since PHP is not a long running process, but you can make a PHP script that executes certain tasks if the script is visited.

I'm not sure if you can use this, but I think Windows itself has some sort of cronjob system (I'm a linux user). I found it at the Drupal website: http://drupal.org/node/31506

Answer (score 0):

How is CodeIgniter tied to your cron job? Are you trying to setup cron jobs from a CodeIgniter application? Are your trying to run a cron job that does some sort of work for your CodeIgniter application? I'm confused as to exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One idea that you may look into is CygWin. It runs a bash shell under windows and it supports a full cron. http://www.cygwin.com/